# Delete trailing ufeff character from output

Tags: windows, go, encoding

I have these two methods:

```
func getSubName() string {

    // execute wecutil es
    out, err := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c", "wecutil", "es").Output()

    //handle any errors
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    return string(out)

}
```

and

```
func getSubInfo(name string) string {
    out, err := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c", "wecutil gs ", name).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }

    output := string(out)
    return output
}
```

getSubName returns a subscription name for Windows Event Forwarding, and getSubInfo grabs that name and returns the full info about the subscription.

My issue is getSubName is returning the correct name but adds a "ufeff" character to the beginning, making the name unrecognizable to Windows.

In this case, the name of the subscription is "test". When I manually pass the value to getSubInfo it returns all the right data, but I get a parameter error when I pass the name given by getSubName. Why? Cause of that "ufeff" character.

I'll be honest, I haven't ran into an issue like this before and I saw that it may have something to do with how the return value is encoded, but I'd like to ask you fine folks first.

Is there a way I can just strip that first character so the "ufeff" character never gets passed?

Thanks!

I included an image showing how the functions are formatting the return value, one that I trimmed with strings.TrimSpace and the other without any trimming.

Notice how the untrimmed value also adds a ton of whitespace to the end (first line): [image]

Comment: From [the kb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/wecutil) "If you use a script to get the names of the subscriptions from the output, you will need to bypass the UTF-8 BOM characters in the first line of the output.". So `U+FEFF` is a [byte order mark](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1); what you are seeing indicates that the following bytes are using "UTF-16, big-endian" encoding; when I run the command on my PC (`wecutil es > tmp.txt`) the output file begins with `ef bb bf` (indicating UTF-8 - get the same from your go app).

Answer (score 0):

**FIX**

Aright, so we need to get rid of the "ufeff" character without using the `strings.TrimSpace` function. From what I can tell from your question the character is at 
 the end of the string.

1. Add this function to your app

```
func TrimFirst(str string) string {
   for i := range s {
        if i > 0 {
            return s[i:]
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

2. Change your return statement to

```
return TrimFirst(output)
```

This should take off the the first character of your string. Which shoud be that "ufeff"

**WHY**

I suspect you are getting this random "ufeff" character because It is built into windows and is 
 some kind of formatting character.

Comment: You can try this: `str = strings.Replace(str, "\ufeff", "", 1)`